# define-key doesn't seem to work on certain keymap

Tags: key-bindings

I'm trying to add some bindings to `undo-tree-visualizer-mode-map`. To do so I use:

```
(define-key undo-tree-visualizer-mode-map (kbd "S-l") 'undo-tree-visualizer-quit)
```

But it doesn't work, and if I do `describe-keymap` afterwards I see that the binding wasn't added.

There seems to be a few keymap where this behavior happens, such as `ivy-occur-mode-map` and `Info-mode-map` as well.

Any idea why is that? And how can I add bindings to those keymaps?

Comment: What is `describe-keymap`? My emacs does not know it and I cannot find it in the elisp manual. Where does it come from?

Comment: @NickD describe-keymap is an interactive autoloaded Lisp function in ‘help-fns+.el’. It basically pretty prints all bindings to commands in a given keymap.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> S-l
> ```

You need to use `L` rather than `S-l`.

This is a quirk of key sequences in Emacs -- for letters (a-z), the shift modifier syntax `S-` won't do what you want, *unless* `C-` is also used in the sequence.

You should therefore write upper-case letters explicitly in key sequences.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/38180797/324105

For clarity:

```el
(kbd "L")
"L"

(kbd "S-l")
[33554540]

(kbd "C-l")
"^L"

(kbd "C-L")
"^L"

(kbd "C-S-l")
[33554444]
```

Arguably Emacs ought to translate `[33554540]` to `"L"`, or otherwise recognise it as intended, but in practice (at least at present) that doesn't happen.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that. That's good to know, but I also realized my mistake, I was doing eval-last-sexp but my define-key was quoted `'` and somehow I was assuming it was evaluating without the quote.